# Laravel: how to put each value array to new array

Tags: laravel

i have below array :

```
$file = {"0": ["finalRate54000"],"1": ["finalRate20000"],"2": ["finalRate1000"]}
```

i want to make new array with result below:

```
{
"3": [
    "finalRate54000"
],
"19": [
    "finalRate20000"
],
"21": [
    "finalRate1000"
]
```

}

and my code is like this:

```
        foreach ($file as $kei => $value) {
            $result[] = $value;
        }
        foreach (Session::get('cartGrouped') as $key => $cartItem){   
            foreach ($result as $i => $data) {
                $response[$i] = $data;
                
                array_push($shipper, $response[$i]);
                $seller_products[\App\Product::find($cartItem['id'])->user_id] = $response[$i];
                }   
        }
        return $seller_products;
```

code above give me output:

```
{
"3": [
    "finalRate1000"
],
"19": [
    "finalRate1000"
],
"21": [
    "finalRate1000"
]
```

}

can someone help me?

Comment: Add the proper input and expected output to the question

Comment: Have you tries `print_r(array_values($file))` ?